# Calculating Band Gap Energy When Absorption Spectra Shifts with Concentration?

Tags: spectroscopy, energy, absorption

[image]

I am not a chemist. However, from some experimental work I have been doing, I have found that the intensity of the spectrum changes with dilution, this makes sense. However, when calculating the band gap energy through Tauc's equation for band gap (ie: taking the line of the energy vs $(ahv)^p$ x intercept) will be affected by the dilution. The line of best fit on the energy graph gets less and less sloped resulting in a changing bandgap. A

If the band gap is an intrinsic property of the material, how can this be a trustable method for measuring bandgap if it is affected by concentration?

Comment: Hint: What is alpha? Is it absorbance only? Also see the nice paper "How To Correctly Determine the Band Gap Energy of Modified Semiconductor Photocatalysts Based on UV−Vis Spectra" Phys. Chem. Lett. 2018, 9, 6814−6817

Comment: The absorbance is related to concentration by a very famous approximation called Beer's law.

Comment: You will notice that the spectrum does not change with dilution other than in magnitude as expected. You should find or measure the fluorescence spectrum, the  'band gap' is fairly accurately the mid point between longest absorption and shortest emission peaks, when converted to wavenumbers

Comment: For anyone with a future question like this: to calculate bandgap from absorbance (not emission spectrum as some have suggested) you must normalize the spectrum before applying tauc.